# Create array from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Below is my JSON object

```
var validation_messages ={
"test1": [{
    "1": {

        "rssi": -25,

    }
}, {
    "2": {

        "rssi": -25,

    }
}],
"test2": [{
    "15": {

        "rssi": -10,
                }
}, {
    "19": {

        "rssi": -21,

    }
}]
```

}

and below is what I have tried

var rssival= [];
for (var key in validation_messages) {

```
var obj = validation_messages[key];

for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
  for(x in obj[i]){

   rssival.push(obj[i][x].rssi);
  } 
}
```

}
console.log(rssival)

I am getting output as

```
[-25, -25, -10, -21]
```

But I need an output as

```
[[-25, -25], [-10, -21]]
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
var validation_messages={"00:11:74:41:3d:f0":[{1:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}},{2:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}}],"00:23:68:bd:6c:19":[{15:{channel:1,type:0,rssi:-10,rate:1}},{19:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-21,rate:54}}]};

var result = Object.keys(validation_messages).map(function(k){
  var tmp = [];
  validation_messages[k].forEach(function(o){ 
    for(var k in o){
      tmp.push(o[k].rssi)
    }
  })
  return tmp
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what you need?

```js
var validation_messages={"00:11:74:41:3d:f0":[{1:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}},{2:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}}],"00:23:68:bd:6c:19":[{15:{channel:1,type:0,rssi:-10,rate:1}},{19:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-21,rate:54}}]};

var rssival = [];

for (var key in validation_messages) {
  var obj = validation_messages[key];
  var aux = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for (x in obj[i]) {
      aux.push(obj[i][x].rssi);
    }
  }
  rssival.push(aux);
}
console.log(rssival);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/etbzjs0x/

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put you code (*JS/CSS/HTML*) and make it executable.

Comment: I have just formatted input so that emphasis is on your logic. If not required, you can revert it

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

```js
var obj = {"00:11:74:41:3d:f0":[{1:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}},{2:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-25,rate:24}}],"00:23:68:bd:6c:19":[{15:{channel:1,type:0,rssi:-10,rate:1}},{19:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-21,rate:54}}]},
    result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(v) {
      var arr = [];
      obj[v].forEach(c => arr.push(c[Object.keys(c)].rssi));
      return arr;
    });

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure how its working, but this will not work if you have multiple keys. Though clever approach for this case. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for pointing it out. Could you provide me some counter example, when my code won't work properly?

Comment: Try adding `{3:{channel:1,type:2,rssi:-30,rate:24}}` in `"00:11:74:41:3d:f0"` and try again.

Comment: @Rajesh I have added it like you said, but I just think that it works... am I wrong?

Comment: My apologies. Was on call so typed incorrect. Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu62f9ad/)

Comment: Trick is in understanding why your approach works. Once you figure it out, it will become obvious to you why it will fail

Comment: @Rajesh Yep, I see it now and you are right. But actually, I just wonder what's the point of adding some more functionality to your code, which the OP wasn't even asking for. It's just overcomplicating/overwriting the OP question. If we would try to solve **every** question on SO with *"what if"* approach, there would be hundreds of lines of code (: OP asked question, provided an example and desired result and my code actually solves it. It's just my opinion, though.

Comment: Thats true but its a subjective call. As developer our jobs is to have insight. Just solving immediate problem will fail sooner than you imagine. Its always better to little out of scope and handle few obvious cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could group all properties with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var validation_messages = validation_messages = { "00:11:74:41:3d:f0": [{ "1": { channel: 1, type: 2, rssi: -25, rate: 24 } }, { "2": { channel: 1, type: 2, rssi: -25, rate: 24 } }], "00:23:68:bd:6c:19": [{ "15": { channel: 1, type: 0, rssi: -10, rate: 1 } }, { "19": { channel: 1, type: 2, rssi: -21, rate: 54 } }] },
    grouped = Object.keys(validation_messages).map(function (k) {
        return validation_messages[k].reduce(function (r, o) {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (l) {
                r.push(o[l].rssi);
            });
            return r;
        }, []);
    });

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: I think that you have overcomplicated it. Two loops are enough for this case. (:

Comment: @Kinduser Third loop is required for cases where user has more than 1 item.

Comment: it's a complete dynamic approach.